# Locating the /dev entry to make partitions on an SD card

Tags: linux, partition, block-device, sd-card

I am trying to create partition of SD card, for this  I am following this [tutorial](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard%3aExpanding_File_System_Partition_On_A_microSD). When I type the command

```
ll /dev/mmcblk*
```

I got this

```
ls: cannot access /dev/mmcblk*: No such file or directory
```

So, I check the list of items in /dev by typing this command

```
ls /dev/
```

I got a big list of items but there is nothing like `mmcblk0` or `mmcblk1`. The list I am getting is this

```
autofs           dvdrw     loop4               psaux  ram6    sdb       tty10  tty24  tty38  tty51  tty8       ttyS2   ttyS5    vcs6
block            ecryptfs  loop5               ptmx   ram7    sdb1      tty11  tty25  tty39  tty52  tty9       ttyS20  ttyS6    vcs7
bsg              fb0       loop6               pts    ram8    sg0       tty12  tty26  tty4   tty53  ttyprintk  ttyS21  ttyS7    vcsa
btrfs-control    fd        loop7               ram0   ram9    sg1       tty13  tty27  tty40  tty54  ttyS0      ttyS22  ttyS8    vcsa1
bus              full      loop-control        ram1   random  sg2       tty14  tty28  tty41  tty55  ttyS1      ttyS23  ttyS9    vcsa2
cdrom            fuse      mapper              ram10  rfkill  shm       tty15  tty29  tty42  tty56  ttyS10     ttyS24  uhid     vcsa3
cdrw             hidraw0   mcelog              ram11  rtc     snapshot  tty16  tty3   tty43  tty57  ttyS11     ttyS25  uinput   vcsa4
char             hpet      mei                 ram12  rtc0    snd       tty17  tty30  tty44  tty58  ttyS12     ttyS26  urandom  vcsa5
console          input     mem                 ram13  sda     sr0       tty18  tty31  tty45  tty59  ttyS13     ttyS27  v4l      vcsa6
core             kmsg      net                 ram14  sda1    stderr    tty19  tty32  tty46  tty6   ttyS14     ttyS28  vcs      vcsa7
cpu              log       network_latency     ram15  sda2    stdin     tty2   tty33  tty47  tty60  ttyS15     ttyS29  vcs1     vga_arbiter
cpu_dma_latency  loop0     network_throughput  ram2   sda3    stdout    tty20  tty34  tty48  tty61  ttyS16     ttyS3   vcs2     vhost-net
disk             loop1     null                ram3   sda4    tty       tty21  tty35  tty49  tty62  ttyS17     ttyS30  vcs3     video0
dri              loop2     port                ram4   sda5    tty0      tty22  tty36  tty5   tty63  ttyS18     ttyS31  vcs4     zero
dvd              loop3     ppp                 ram5   sda6    tty1      tty23  tty37  tty50  tty7   ttyS19     ttyS4   vcs5
```

I have followed this tutorial before but I do not any idea what's wrong this time. So,please tell how to get mmcblk list.

Comment: Can you check to see if the SD card is mounted? If you are trying to partition it, it cannot be mounted.

Comment: I am newbie, I dont know how to check, please tell me command for this

Comment: try this: `df | grep -q partition`

Comment: eject and re-insert the SD card, then type `dmesg` at a terminal.  Text will fly past, but you're interested in the last few lines.  Is there anything there that's relevant?  It might be worth running `dmesg` once, inserting the SD Card and then run `dmesg` again to help spot the difference.

Comment: @garethTheRed:- there is a change in last line, when sd card is not inserted, there is one extra line:-
[ 3087.215682] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 6

Comment: @ryekayo:- df | grep -q partition make no difference

Comment: Insert the SD Card and run `dmesg` again.  See what info you get.  Also note what @gena2x said.  You have a `sdb` in your `/dev`.  Is that the SD Card?

Comment: I tried one more time, this when I remove SD card, I got this line in end:-
[ 3645.182867] sdb: detected capacity change from 15976103936 to 0

so, sdb1 is my sd card name?

Comment: I tried Gena instruction, that is I tried ls /dev with and without sd Card , the only difference is is sdb1 is extra there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SD card is not necessary visible as `/dev/mmcblk*`. Another possibility is `/dev/sd*`.

You can find name the either by looking into the `dmesg` output. Other way is to eject card, type `ls /dev`, insert card, do `ls /dev` again and find the difference.

Comment: /dev/sd* command showing this error
sudo: /dev/sda: command not found

Comment: @tabish `/dev/sd*` isn't a command, it's a pattern that might match some files. RUn `echo /dev/sd*` or `ls -l /dev/sd*`.

Comment: `sudo dmesg -wH` will *follow* to allow for monitoring; identically, `journalctl -x -t kernel -f` works as well (depending on the environment).

Answer (score 2):

Try on the command line in konsole:

```
lsblk
```

which should list all of your hard drives and their partitions.